# Convert Date Format from character "11JAN2016:00:00:00.000"

Tags: r, lubridate

I am looking to convert this character vector to a date format

I have tried various methods though have not been successful so far. Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?strptime` for format details

```
as.Date(x, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2016-01-11"
```

---

Or if you want it in date-time format

```
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2016-01-11 GMT"
```

---

With `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hms(x)
#[1] "2016-01-11 UTC"
```

and if you want only date

```
ymd(dmy_hms(x))
#[1] "2016-01-11"
```

**data**

```
x <- "11JAN2016:00:00:00.000"
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! It says I can accept an answer in 9 minutes but let it be known that you nailed this in about 3 minutes of my positing the question.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(data)
#[1] "2016-01-11"
```

#### data

```
data <- "11JAN2016:00:00:00.000"
```